# Why does my program on C not run and give me unused variable error?

Tags: c, sum, unused-variables

I'm writing a program that adds the numbers from 1-5 and prints out the sum. It was working a week ago but today I got unused variable error and don't know where i'm wrong.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int sum = 0;
    int num;
    for(int num=1; num<=5; num++){
        sum = sum + num;
    }
    printf(" The sum of numbers 1 to 5 are %d",sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you declare num and reassign another num?

Comment: You have two variables named `num`, the second is defined and used within the scope of the loop, the first is unused as the compiler says.

Comment: I'm not trying to.

Comment: even after I delete that num. It says build failed

Comment: What was the reason given for the failed build? Which line was objected to?

Comment: linker common failed with exit code

Comment: @J.Doe The program is ok. Your issue is with your compiler or environment

Comment: Remove the type on `num` in the loop

Comment: [delete int num;](http://ideone.com/r2Rm84)

Answer (score 1):

You first declare a `num` variable of type `int`, and then redeclare it in the `for` loop.

So you should either remove the `int` in the for loop (C89):

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int sum = 0;
    int num;
    for(num=1; num<=5; num++){
        sum = sum + num;
    }
    printf(" The sum of numbers 1 to 5 are %d",sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Or remove the `num` variable first declaration (C99):

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int num=1; num<=5; num++){
        sum = sum + num;
    }
    printf(" The sum of numbers 1 to 5 are %d",sum);

    return 0;
}
```

You compiler may also say "Unused variable" because you do not use the `main` function parameters (`argc` and `argv`). You can fix this by using `main(void)`:

```
int main(void) {
    /* ... */
```